# Unable to properly create managed object and save it in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uialertcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVYMc.png)I have created a simple example of my issue that I am not able to find the solution.

There is a core data stack in the App delegate with a static var to retrieve the persistent container.  I access this var in both view controllers and get the moc (persistantContainer.viewController) used by each controller.

I have created two entities (Collection and Deck) in core data. Each with one attribute (title: String). Collection has a "to many" relationship with Deck and Decks inverse is a "to-one". I have two tableview controllers, each with a fetched results controller. There is an add button in the navigation bar for each view controller that allows the user to add a Collection or a Deck (respectively).  I can perform the add Collection and have the fetchedResultsController delegate methods fire and display the added item just fine. When selecting a row item for Collections I segue to the second tableview controller to display decks for the selected collection.

The fetchedResultsController in the second TableViewController has a predicate that checks the collection relationship of the Decks to be the same as the collection selected. I only want the decks that are part of the collection selected to be displayed.

This part works fine, but when the user selects to add a Deck, it gets added but does not fire the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods to show the deck in the tableview.  If I slide back to the collections view then select the same Collection again, the deck now shows up. So i know it was added.

The problem is two parts:
1) Why is the NSfetchedResultsControllerDelegate not firing
2) I want the user to input the Collection and Deck names while adding via a UIAlertController with a text field. I have set this up and it works for the CollectionViewController but am unable to get it working in the DecksViewController.  I really don't know what thread I should run the code on or if the AlertAction handler is in a background thread.

I have looked through this forum and apple's forum for any help for the last two days.

Things I have tried. Main Que Dispatch, passing managed objectID, getting the managedobjectcontext from the passed collection object, removing the predicate all together to see if I can get it to work. Nothing is getting the result I am expecting.

var collection: CollectionMO!

```
    private lazy var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<DeckMO> = {
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<DeckMO> = DeckMO.fetchRequest()
        let sort1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort1]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "collection == %@", collection)
        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        frc.delegate = self
        return frc

    }()

    @IBAction func addDeck(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        nameDeck() // this is the preferred method and remaining code in this action test code to get it working
        let newDeck = DeckMO(context: viewContext)
        newDeck.title = "Deck \((frc.fetchedObjects?.count)! + 1) in \(collection.title ?? "")"
        collection.addToDecks(newDeck)
    }

    private func nameDeck(_ deck:DeckMO? = nil) {

        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: deck?.title != nil ? "Retitle Deck:" : "Enter New Deck Title",
                                           message: deck?.title ?? "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField: UITextField) in
            textField.placeholder = deck?.title ?? "Enter Deck Title"
        })

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { action in
            if let text1 = alert.textFields?.first, text1.hasText, text1.text != deck?.title {
                if let updateDeck = deck {
                    updateDeck.title = text1.text
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let newDeck = DeckMO(context: self.viewContext)
                        newDeck.title = text1.text
                        newDeck.collection = self.collection
                    }
                }
            }
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

The DeckViewController should display the deck added immediately after adding and the DeckViewController should only display Decks of the selected Collection from the previous viewController.